# parse log file using powershell, and send email notification

Tags: c++, windows, powershell

Thank you for taking time and helping me out,

I am trying to create powershell script to read from log file. If "Buy" or "sell" word found then send me an email notification, The script should read last line only and once only, else multiple notifications

location of the log file
"C:\Program Files\LMFX MetaTrader 4 Terminal\MQL4\Logs\20181206.log"

```
> tail -5 (last 5 entry of the log file) 0  19:44:20.644    indicator1
> EURUSD,Daily: initialized 0   19:44:20.644    indicator2 EURUSD,Daily:
> initialized 0 19:44:20.645    indicator3 EURUSD,Daily: initialized
> 0 19:44:20.646    indicator4 EURUSD,Daily: initialized
> 0 19:44:20.659    indicator5 EURUSD,Daily: Alert:  ! BUY !  -  EURUSD
> 0 19:44:20.659    indicator5 EURUSD,Daily: Alert:  ! SELL !  -  EURUSD
```

`

```
#Powershell Script
$logDir = "C:\Program Files\LMFX MetaTrader 4 Terminal\MQL4\Logs"

function Send-ToEmail([string]$email){
$user = "Sender@email.com"
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "PASSWORD" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $user, $pass
$body = ":("
$mailParam = @{
    To = "Sender@email.com"
    From = "ALERT ALERT <Reciever@email.com>"
    Subject = "ALERT ALERT ALERT ALERT"
    Body = $body
    SmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
    Port = 587
    Credential = $cred
    #Attachments = "none"     
}

# Send the email with all parameters
Send-MailMessage @mailParam -UseSsl
```

}

```
# create a variable to store the previous log line in
$previousLogLine = ''
while ($true) {
$latestLog = Get-ChildItem -Path $logDir -Filter '*.log' | Sort-Object 
LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
Write-Host "Reading from $($latestLog.Name)"

$logLine = Get-Content -Path $latestLog.FullName -Tail 1
# if this line is different from the previously stored line
# and it contains either "sell" or "buy", then send the email
if ($logLine -ne $previousLogLine -and $logLine -match 'sell|buy') { 
    Send-ToEmail -email "Reciever@email.com"
    # remember this line to compare with the line we get in the next 
    iteration
    $previousLogLine = $logLine
    }
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    cls
   }
`
```

Comment: Why did you break the code in my answer and shared that on codeshare.io?

Comment: Have you considered using python for this?

Answer (score 0):

Change your last part to following, I don't think -wait switch is suitable in this case.
Use an array to store all items sent.

```
while ($true) {
$sent = @()
Get-Content -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Tickmill MT4 Client Terminal\MQL4\Logs\$latest" -Tail 1 | %{if(($_ -match "sell" -or $_ -match "buy") -and $sent -notcontains $_){Send-ToEmail  -email "receiver@email.com"; $sent += $_}}

start-sleep 2

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the update, however the issue is if the last logged item was sell or buy and no new message after that the script keeps sending emails,

how can i code to only send one email and wait 
-wait didnt work out

Comment: Thank you for the update, script is sending email again and again for same log/alert due to the fact their is no new alerts "last line which matched the alert"

how can i code to only send one email and wait for new logs 
-wait didnt work out

Comment: --------I modified the last part the however it still repeating the last log/alerts ------


while ($true) {
$sent = @()
$alert = Get-Content -Path "C:\Program Files\LMFX MetaTrader 4 Terminal\MQL4\Logs\$latest" -Tail 1 | Out-String
Get-Content -Path "C:\Program Files\LMFX MetaTrader 4 Terminal\MQL4\Logs\$latest" -Tail 1 | %{if(($_ -match "sell" -or $_ -match "buy" -and $_ -ne $alert ) -and $sent -notcontains $_){Send-ToEmail  -email "aj.saini94@gmail.com"; $sent += $_}}

start-sleep 1

}

Comment: Did you fix it? Yeah, I didn't consider enough when answering the question.@AjSaini

Comment: Hi Guys, 
Still not luck, I see the entry in log however no email notification :(

Comment: https://codeshare.io/aymRp0

I am not able to post the updated code here,

Can you someone help 
Please i just want when i get message from log (buy) or (sell) - receive and email

Comment: @AjSaini You have put your comment below the wrong answer.. In the link, all is see is the code I gave you, but with this part wrongly changed: `if ($logLine -ne $previousLogLine -and $logLine -match 'sell|buy')` into `if ($previousLogLine -notcontains $logLine -and $logLine -match 'sell|buy')`. That won't work my friend, because `$previousLogLine` is not an array, but a single string. Also you have put a `cls` in the code _WITHIN_ the `while` loop of all places!! Please if my code didn't work for you, explain it. If the code did help you with your problem, then Accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is to:

1. check the latest log file inside the loop
2. remember the last line that contained "buy" or "sell" in order not to send the same line as email over and over again

Perhaps something like this:

```
$logDir = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Tickmill MT4 Client Terminal\MQL4\Logs\"

function Send-ToEmail([string]$email){
    $user = "sender@email.com"
    $pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "PASSWORD" -AsPlainText -Force
    $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $user, $pass
    $body = ":("
    $mailParam = @{
        To = "sender@email.com"
        From = "ALERT ALERT <Reciever@email.com>"
        Subject = "ALERT : #tail last line"
        Body = $body 
        SmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
        Port = 587
        Credential = $cred
        #Attachments = "none"     
    }

    # Send the email with all parameters
    Send-MailMessage @mailParam -UseSsl
 }

# create a variable to store the previous log line in
$previousLogLine = ''
while ($true) {
    $latestLog = Get-ChildItem -Path $logDir -Filter '*.log' | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
    Write-Host "Reading from $($latestLog.Name)"

    $logLine = Get-Content -Path $latestLog.FullName -Tail 1
    # if this line is different from the previously stored line
    # and it contains either "sell" or "buy", then send the email
    if ($logLine -ne $previousLogLine -and $logLine -match 'sell|buy') { 
        Send-ToEmail -email "receiver@email.com"
        # remember this line to compare with the line we get in the next iteration
        $previousLogLine = $logLine
    }

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
}
```

As you can see, I've also changed `LastAccessTime` into `LastWriteTime` for the file, because I think that is more appropriate.
After testing, don't forget to change this line `To = "sender@email.com"` into `To = $email`.

Hope that helps